# What is the best route from Fresno, CA to Cheyenne, WY?

Tags: usa

I am traveling in a 40ft motorhome and towing a SUV. What is the best route from Fresno, CA. to Cheyenne, WY?

Comment: You need to edit in what requiments you look for in 'best'. Shortest, cheapest, easiest, possible at all?

Comment: Really, we can't make your itinerary. You could ask if there is an obvious road on the map that in fact can't accommodate your vehicles. You could ask if there's a well known route that is rich in Walmarts if you plan to overnight in their parking lots, or in state parks that accept motorhomes, or is incredibly scenic. You could say you want to avoid 4 line highways or stick exclusively to them. We can't plan your route but we can give you facts -- if you ask for the specific ones you happen to need for the decision, which may not be the ones someone else would want.